# Is there a more compact option to check if a variable equals "this" OR "that"?

Tags: javascript, comparison

I want to check if a variable (in this case `sampleVariable`) is equal to `THIS` or `THAT`:

```
if(sampleVariable == "THIS" || chosenVerb == "THAT")
```

The above code should work fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to simplify and compact it - for example, something like this (this probably isn't how you do it, just an example):

```
if(sampleVariable == "THIS" || "THAT")
```

I'm fairly certain the above doesn't work since it will check for the two statements being true separately.

I found [this](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/03/14/better-ways-of-comparing-a-javascript-string-to-multiple-values/) website, which seems to be what I'm looking for. They say that this code is the best way to go around it:

```
if (fruit.match(/^(banana|lemon|mango|pineapple)$/)) {
    handleYellowFruit();
}
```

Is this still the way that this is supposed to be done (since the blog post I linked above was published over half a decade ago)? If so, what are these characters in the parentheses: `/ ^ $` ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you only have 2 cases the first example is perfectly perfectly fine and is the best/simplest/most readable way to do it.

Comment: Okay, in my research I couldn't find the duplicate questions - I must have used different terms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on browser support and ability to polyfill, I'd try [`array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if ((["THIS", "THAT"]).includes(sampleVariable)) {
```